# Openfiledialog filter doesn't restrict files to open by typing full file path in File name text box C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I am using the `OpenFileDialog` to open some specific file type, to do that I set the `Filter` property of `OpenFileDialog`. The filter setting does only hiding the file which are out of filter extensions, but user can still select  those files by typing the file name in `OpenFileDialog` 'File Names:' text box. 
I want user should not be able to select the file which are out of filter settings even typing the path manually in openFileDialog box 'File Names:' textbox.

This is the code.

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EncryptFile();
    }

    public void EncryptFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "Office Files|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt";
        dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        dialog.Title = "Please select an office file to encrypt.";
        string fileName = "";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            fileName = dialog.FileName; 
            /// doing something
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  Use its FileOk event to reject files you don't like.

Comment: @HansPassant, I am not saying this is a bug! rather I was looking for any inbuilt way in OpenFileDialog it self so my explicit check can remove that you are suggesting as well.